# I can't use extra speakers through HDMI in Ubuntu

Tags: sound

I have my notebook connected with my monitor via HDMI.
If I change the output in the sound settings in my Ubuntu 18.04 the sound plays over my monitor, how it should be. Thats fine, but now if I connect my extra Logitech speakers with the monitor via the audio input, the sound still gets played over the monitor not over the extra speakers. Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is not about Information Security. You probably meant to go to [ubuntu.se].

Comment: Oh i Just found a similar topic on Stackexchange so I thought its right there... But okay, thanks for putting it here

Comment: Information Security is for things like hacking. This is not about hacking.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily change the audio output device. Just go to Settings --> Sound --> Output device and select the audio device from the drop down.

[image]

Comment: I have only the Option to select Notebook or HDMI, but Not the speakers which are connected with the Monitor...

Comment: Can you check that if the speakers are working on any other OS but on the system? The speakers should've shown in the dropdown if they were properly connected.

Comment: If I plug the speakers directly to my notebook it works! Only if I plug em to the monitor it does not work... But would be nicer if I could connect em to the monitor... One moment I try it on an other OS.

Comment: Tried it with a Windows 10 OS it's also not working. For clarity: the speakers it self are working perfekt if I plug them to the notebook direct. Only if I plug them to my monitor they dont work...

Comment: Topic can bei closed!, problem was the broken audio output Adapter on the monitor

Comment: That happens time to time. Lol